# How to call a delegated click function?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    console.log('title');
});
```

I can call this function this way:

```
$('.title').click();
```

And what if the function is written like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.title', function() {
    console.log('title');
});
```

How to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way

```js
$(document).on('click', '.title', function() {
    console.log('title');
});

$('.title').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="title">title</button>
```

Comment: It seems my problem is  - `title` doesn't exist on the page. What in such a case?

Comment: @puerto you are trying to trigger a click event on a non-existant element? can you explain further

Comment: it's ok, I simply add a `title`. Thanks a lot.